# glue.driver.aggregate.numFailedTasks CloudWatch metric doesn't log failure when Glue job fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I have a Glue PySpark job which has failed after approx 2 mins with an `AnalysisException` and a Run Status of `Failed`. I want to detect it for a CloudWatch alarm. In CloudWatch metrics I'm expecting it to record a count of 1 over the period, but it's recording 0.  I'm using the following metric config:

```
   MetricName: glue.driver.aggregate.numFailedTasks
   JobRunId: ALL
   JobName: <MyGlueJobName>
   Statistic: Sum
   Period: 1 min
   Type: Count
```

It appears other metrics are working e.g. `glue.driver.jvm.heap.used` but not [numFailedTasks](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-glue-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/monitoring-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-metrics.md). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar problem/requirement with our glue jobs. We have many jobs and need to monitor success and failure. We've also experienced that the built-in metrics aren't really reliable. But even if they were, they don't really answer the question of whether or not a job was successful. We found a good way for us by generating custom metrics in a generic way for all jobs. This also works for existing jobs afterwards without having to change the code. I wrote an article about it: https://medium.com/@ettefette/metrics-for-aws-glue-jobs-as-you-know-them-from-lambda-functions-e5e1873c615c

Comment: Can you please add some additional details in the answer itself from the blog post. In case the external link becomes stale or down even then your answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I managed to get around this problem was to create a custom metric. I created a metric using [put_metric_data](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_data). I call it when an exception is raised in the pyspark script.